# Unable to split by "==" or "!=" in java

Tags: java, regex, split

I have been trying to split a line by `==` or `!=`. I have tried inside regex these: `={2,2}` or `//=//=` or `//=//!`, but none of them worked. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you!
P.S. `string.split("==")` is not convenient for me, as I want a regex because I want to split by multiple delimiters, not only by the two mentioned above.

Comment: Just do `string.split("==")`

Comment: `String.split()` **does** use a regex

Comment: I fail to see how you think `//=//=` or `//=//!` would even be a valid thing to try.

Comment: things found on the internet, not mine. what thing would be valid enough to try, then?

Answer (score 2):

you'll need to utilise the regex OR ( `|` ) operator to split by more than one criteria.

```
String result = input.split("==|!=");
```